# Duplicating an html element that passes id parameters in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have jquery function that pass Id parameters in the MarkUp. And it works fine,  when I clone the function it returns the same Id's. I'd like it to return different id's... how do I go about to have different id parameters?

thats the function:

```
    var generateMarkup = function(statusid, emailid) {
        return '<div class = "divAddId" style="float:left;"><div id="wfEmailStatus' + statusid + "_" + emailid + 'Header">' +
            '<input type="checkbox" name="wfEmailStatus' + ($('#workflowModalTabStatus' + statusid + "_" + emailid).length + 1) + 'Conditional" class="typ3 paleText" id="wfEmailStatus' + ($('#workflowModalTabStatus' + statusid + "_" + emailid).length + 1) + 'Conditional" value="Y" disabled="disabled" />' +
            '<label for="wfEmailStatus' + ($('#workflowModalTabStatus' + statusid + "_" + emailid).length + 1) + 'Conditional" class="typ2 noTxtSelect1 paleText"> Delivery Conditional On Field &nbsp;&nbsp;</label>' +
            '<input type="text" name="wfEmailStatus' + ($('#workflowModalTabStatus' + statusid + "_" + emailid).length + 1) + 'ConditionalFields" class="typ1 shad2 paleText" id="wfEmailStatus' + ($('#workflowModalTabStatus' + statusid + "_" + emailid).length + 1) + 'ConditionalFields" ' +
            'value="" disabled="disabled" style="width:310px" />' +
            '<input value = "Remove Field" type="button" class="smallbutt3" id="workflowEmailDeliveryStatus' + ($('#workflowModalTabStatus' + statusid + "_" + emailid).length + 1) + 'Remove" style="float:middle" disabled="disabled"></button></div></div>';
    };
```

And that is my click event:

```
 $('.smallbutt2').click(function() {
            $parent = $(this).parent();
            $rows =$parent.find('.divAddId');
            var $newItem = $(generateMarkup(statusid, emailid));
            $last = $rows.last();
            $newItem.insertAfter($last);
            var $break = $("<br />");
            var $button = $newItem.find('.smallbutt3').first();

            $button.click(function() {
                $newItem.hide();
                $newItem.remove();
                $break.remove();
            });
            $button.fadeIn();
        });
```

Comment: Are you sure you really need these elements to have IDs? If they're repeated, you should probably use a class instead.

Comment: I understand that Barmar & I am using class... And yes i need those id parameters... I thought of using a loop but that didn't work out... I'm hoping there's an easier way...!

Comment: It looks like you're doing it right. You just need to increment `statusid` each time you call `generateMarkup`.

Comment: Thats what I need help with... Everytime I increment I get the undefined error on Firebug...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var statusid = 1; // Initialize statusid

$('.smallbutt2').click(function() {
            $parent = $(this).parent();
            $rows =$parent.find('.divAddId');
            var $newItem = $(generateMarkup(statusid, emailid));
            statusid++; // Increment it after generating a new item
            $last = $rows.last();
            $newItem.insertAfter($last);
            var $break = $("<br />");
            var $button = $newItem.find('.smallbutt3').first();

            $button.click(function() {
                $newItem.hide();
                $newItem.remove();
                $break.remove();
            });
            $button.fadeIn();
        });
```

Comment: What did I do differently from you?

Comment: Well, you initialized the statusid... I had a variable 'count' initialized count = 0...